# Uninitialized float (C++)

Tags: c++, initialization

If you want to initialize a float with an "uninitialized" state what value would you choose? (value easily testable and the least likely to be confused with an actual value)

> float min=-999999.;

could have problems potentially either being confused with an actual value or even being tested due to fuzzy float roundings (and it looks naive :-)

Comment: `boost::optional<float>` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to avoid using valid values of `float`, you could use a NAN:

```
#include <limits>

....
float min = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
```

You can then use `std::isnan` to check:

```
#include <cmath>

....
bool not_cool = std::isnan(min);
```

Comment: Good, thanks. Being in C99 seems that isnan is not available but comparing the float to the std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN() seems to work

Comment: @Juan Be really careful about comparing values which could be NaN. So running if(myVal == std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()) will always be false even if myVal is set to std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN(). You need an isnan equivalent. [EDIT: see http://ideone.com/hzFCyB]

Comment: Thanks Mike, seems that here we are in uncertain territories :-)

Comment: Update: In VStudio 2008 there's _isnan()

Answer (score 5):

You can use [NAN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/02/8679191.aspx). However

> The problem was the use of an uninitialized floating point variable.
>   Unlike integers, not all bit patterns are valid for use as floating
>   point values. There is a category of values known as signaling NaNs,
>   or SNaN for short, which are special "not a number" values. If you ask
>   the processor to, it will keep an eye out for these signaling NaNs and
>   raise an "invalid operand" exception when one is encountered. (This,
>   after all, is the whole reason why it's called a signaling NaN.)

Also I would suggest you to use  **[Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)** like this:

```
boost::optional<float> minValue;  // initially unset
```

Comment: Boost.Optional is my choice as well for such "problems", especially it will be soon `std::optional<T>`

Comment: Where does that quote come from? Cite your sources.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:- I have quotes the site in [NAN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/02/8679191.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the variable name `min`, you would want it to be as large as possible. This way, any comparison to this value will be a smaller value, and update your `minValue`.

```
float minValue = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
```

P.S. don't name your variable `min` or you risk name shadowing issues.

Comment: Name shadowing issues aren't really a problem when you actually prepend `std::` to things.

Comment: I just mean potential unwanted behavior in general. Especially since everyone always loves to do `using namespace std` which is just as bad

Comment: @Cyber: Right, so, don't do that.